# sum the coordinates of two geometries via geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Sorry for this naive question; I was wondering if it was possible to add the coordinates of 2 meshes to make a third one?
To illustrate my problem in a simple way, let's imagine that I have two spheres with the same number of points and that I want to generate a third sphere whose coordinates would be the sum of the two others:
[image]

unfortunately this approach does not work and I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out:

[image]

result:

[image]

To "transfer" values from one branch to another, you can use sample index node.

Comment: thx a lot ! :):)